# Partial view update on ajax POST redirecting to form's action method

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor

I have created 2 partial views called _ftpsetupDetails.cshtml and _ftpsetupedit.cshtml
On load of the index page i am loading details partial view onto the below div.

now the problem is on post to the controller after save i am returning the ready only mode detail partial view. But instead of loading the partial view or hit done method of ajax it is redirecing the page to /FT/Edit url with detail partial view html on it. How to make sure the page is not redirected? what am i doing wrong?

```js
//Once user clicks on Save button the below code will post the form data to controller
$(document).on("click", "#updateFTP", function () {
    $.post("/Ftp/Edit", $('form').serialize())
        .done(function (response) {
            alert(response.responseText);
        });
        });
        //On page load i am loading the partialview container witih read only view
            LoadAjaxPage("/Ftp/DetailsByOrgId", "organizationId=" + orgId + "&orgType=" + orgType, "#ftpPartialViewContainer");
            
            //On edit button click i am loading the same div container with edit partial view
            $(document).on("click", "#editFTP", function () {

    // $("#createUserPartialViewContainer").load("/Users/Create?organizationId=" + orgId + "&organizationType=" + orgTypeId);
    LoadAjaxPage("/Ftp/Edit", "organizationId=" + orgId + "&orgType=" + orgType, "#ftpPartialViewContainer");

});
```

```html
  <div id="ftpPartialViewContainer">

                                       </div>
                                        <!--Details HTML partial view code-->
                                            <div class="card shadow mb-3">
        <div class="card-header">
            <p class="text-primary m-0 font-weight-bold"> FTP Setup</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <label for="Name" class="control-label">Name</label>
                    <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" readonly />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <label for="Password" class="control-label">Password</label>
                    <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" readonly />
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <input type="submit" value="Edit" class="btn btn-primary" id="editFTP" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
                                       <!--Edit HTML partial view code-->
                                       @model MyProject.Models.Ftp
@if (this.ViewContext.FormContext == null)
{
    this.ViewContext.FormContext = new FormContext();
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "ftp", FormMethod.Post,))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Please fix the errors")
    <div class="card shadow mb-3">
        <div class="card-header">
            <p class="text-primary m-0 font-weight-bold"> FTP Setup</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <form asp-action="Edit">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="Pkid" />
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="ConnectedTo" />
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="ConnectedToType" />

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <label asp-for="Password" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary " id="updateFTP" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

}
```

Comment: I am not clear about your requirement.Did you want to return _ftpsetupDetails after you post data to `/Ftp/Edit`?What do you mean for `make sure the page is not redirected`?

Comment: So the idea was when the user comes to index page where ftpPartialViewContainer is loaded in display mode. Once user clicks on edit, EDIT(Get) returns the partial view in edit mode and the div is loaded with the edit mode partial view. Now user updates the form and clicks on save. At this moment the expected relsut is to perform Update in controller and return the read only mode partial view to the ajax call. Instead of loading the partial view in container, the page itself is redirected from index to FTP/Edit